# Java .class file name does not match source file name

Tags: java

I just set up JDK 7 on my PC running Windows 7 and created a hello world program called `HelloWorldApp.java`.

When I tried to run it, it said that it couldn't find the file.  I looked in the directory and found the `.class` file, but it was named `HelloWoldApp.class` (note the missing `r`).

Why is this, and should I be concerned?

Comment: Did it really compiled fine? Did you at least get a compiler warning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your source file.  I bet you named the class `HelloWoldApp` inside.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't realize that, I'm very new to Java.

Answer (score 1):

It works just fine for me.

You should probably be concerned if and only if you have double, triple, quadruple,..., and n-tuple checked that you didn't spell the name of the class incorrectly.

You may have reason to be concerned about your spelling.